# Why am I getting this Cache-money error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached, cache-money

I followed the instructions found on the github page exactly. I would post some of my configuration but it matches what's found here on http://github.com/nkallen/cache-money/tree/master

The error reads as follows:

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Mar 05 16:45:09 -0500 2009
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  undefined method `indices' for nil:NilClass
    (__DELEGATION__):2:in `__send__'
    (__DELEGATION__):2:in `indices'
    (__DELEGATION__):2:in `__send__'
    (__DELEGATION__):2:in `indices'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nkallen-cache-money-0.2.5/lib/cash/query/abstract.rb:114:in `indexed_on?'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nkallen-cache-money-0.2.5/lib/cash/query/abstract.rb:56:in `cacheable?'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nkallen-cache-money-0.2.5/lib/cash/query/abstract.rb:15:in `perform'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nkallen-cache-money-0.2.5/lib/cash/query/abstract.rb:7:in `perform'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nkallen-cache-money-0.2.5/lib/cash/finders.rb:24:in `find_every'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1452:in `find_initial'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:587:in `find'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session/active_record_store.rb:113:in `find_by_session_id'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session/active_record_store.rb:79:in `find_by_session_id'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session/active_record_store.rb:288:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1398:in `silence'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session/active_record_store.rb:288:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi/session.rb:279:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi/session.rb:279:in `initialize_without_cgi_reader'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/cgi_ext/session.rb:19:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:94:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:94:in `session'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:130:in `stale_session_check!'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:78:in `session'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1205:in `assign_shortcuts_without_flash'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:166:in `assign_shortcuts'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:519:in `process_without_filters'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_without_session_management_support'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in `handle_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in `dispatch_cgi'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing when you get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cache-money initializer in **config/initializers/cache_money.rb** seems to need the *session_store* as *mem_cache_store*

for me it works like this:

**config/environment.rb**:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :mem_cache_store
```

**config/environments/production.rb**:

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by using ActiveRecord as my session store.

Using the given initializer on the cache money github attempts to use cache money for ActiveRecord::SessionStore (rails 2.3) which isn't a complete ActiveRecord (I assume for performance reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after updating to Rails 2.3. 
I still had the line

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

in my environment.rb
I got it fixed by replacing it with

```
ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store
```

in an initializer file.

Comment: Has using 'config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store' been deprecated?

Comment: Unsure :(. What I can say is that the session_store= ... -line is no longer to be found in environment.rb-Files generated with Rails 2.3 and the 2.3-release notes recommend the above notation